# Using outerHeight(); to measure the same class name, but with different heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The distance of the animation depends on the `item0` height. However, when I use a secondary class to change the height of the div, the jQuery does not takes the new height into practice.

Is it possible to factor in the new height, given by the new class name?

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/28N7M/1/

jQuery:

```
    var height = $('.item0').outerHeight();

    $('p').click(function(){
        $('.item0').animate({top:height}, 300);

    });
```

HTML:

```
    <p>click here</p>

    <div class="item0"></div>
    <div class="item0"></div>
    <div class="item0"></div>
    <div class="item0 half"></div>
```

CSS

```
.item0 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.half {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: so you want the div with class name half to animate a different way?

Comment: when you use class item0 this element have padding-top:5px padding-bottom:5px and height 50px; so your element have 60px; but when you use this var height = $('.half').outerHeight(); your element (this one) will have a height 10px;

Comment: @mcmac wait... what? If the `.item0` has `padding: 5px`, then by adding the class `.half` will inherit the `padding: 5px` from `.item0`.

Comment: sorry @silentw but I don't get it, I write 10px height for a half because in css is set height:10px;

Comment: @mcmac but `height: 10px` will only override the `height` property, not all the other properties defined in the `.item0` class.

Comment: @silentw yes I know I write 10px; because this is new height value not final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('p').click(function(){
     var $this;
     $('.item0').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            top: $this.outerHeight()
        }, 300);
     });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/28N7M/10/)

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is declare your variable '$this' outside of the '.each()'. Right now you are creating a new variable for every '.item0'. All you need is one variable and to change the value of that one variable through every iteration of '.item0'.

Comment: @photodow If I declare the variable outside of the `.each()` method, it will point to the `p` element instead.

Comment: Why are you defining `$this`? It's redundant in this case.

Comment: You're correct, silly mistake, didn't took enough time to spot that mistake, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are first calculating the height, and then defining the click event handler. Obviously you've only calculated the height once and you should recalculate it again. Also you need to calculate it for every item.

Simply calculate the height on click:

```
$('p').click(function () {
    $('.item0').each(function() {
        var height = $(this).outerHeight();

        $(this).animate({top:height}, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: That will always get the height of the first `item0` and not the one that is being clicked on. You'll need to use a `this` or similar to get the right `item0`.

Comment: But he's clicking on `p` not `.item0`. Those are `div`s.

Comment: Oh hang on, I think I get what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, that's right. You're still only getting the height once though and then applying it to all elements, exactly as the original poster was. Other answers solve the issue but you are right that I was wrong on my suggestion of how to fix.

Comment: But you made me realise that the heights need to be calculated separately. Thanks.